How to ignore a soft hyphen in an Xpath 1.0?
I'm trying to find the following button in Selenium (Java):
<bdi id="__label1-__xmlview1--Table-Popup-bdi">My But&shy;ton</bdi>

innerHTML & innerText of the element return My Button only. Outer html returns vale without hyphens as well:
<bdi id="__label1-__xmlview1--Table-Popup-bdi">My Button</bdi>

None of the answers for similar questions work for me, e.g.:
   //bdi[translate(., '&shy;', '') = 'My Button']
   //bdi[translate(., '\u00AD', '') = 'My Button']
   //bdi[contains(@id, 'Table') and contains(@id, 'Popup') and contains(translate(text(), '\u00AD', ''), 'My Button')]
   //bdi[contains(@id, 'Table') and contains(@id, 'Popup') and contains(translate(., '\u00AD', ''), 'My Button')]
   //bdi[contains(@id, 'Table') and contains(@id, 'Popup') and translate(text(), '\u00AD', '')='My Button']
   //bdi[contains(@id, 'Table') and contains(@id, 'Popup') and translate(., '\u00AD', '')='My Button']
   //bdi[translate(., '-', '') = 'My Button']

all of these are unable to find the button. If I provide a name of a button that does not have soft hyphens, the xpaths work alright (so I know it's a problem with the hyphens). replace() does not work, as I'm using Xpath 1.0. Using starts-with and ends-with or contains is not helpful in this case, as this issue occurs in several button names and I'm looking for a more universal solution than hardcoding each name break separately.
I only have DOM to work with, my team doesn't have any contact with developers so any help is appreciated. I'd love to understand what's happening here.
Edited:
Please see VGR's comment for solution that worked for me.

Does //bdi[translate(string(), '\u00AD', '') = 'My Button'] work?

Remember that .text() method will return displayed text.   So at that point it will be "My Button", or "My But-ton" depending on viewport size.  Is it always displayed left-to-right?

@VGR yes! so simple! thank you (with lots of exclamation points)!

@browsermator yes, it's left-to-right. the point was to create a locator that would work no matter what screen size. VGR proposal of using string() instead of text() or . is what solved my problem.

this comment contained the solution - using string() instead of text() or . Read more: Difference between text() and string()

Does //bdi[translate(string(), '\u00AD', '') = 'My Button'] work?

–
VGR
Commented Oct 21 at 14:14

Perhaps
//bdi[starts-with(text(), 'My But') and ends-with(text(), 'ton)]
Or
//bdi[matches(text(), 'My But\W?ton')] (requires xpath 2.0)

Hi, as mentioned in the description, using starts-with and ends-with or contains is not helpful in this case, as this issue occurs in several button names and I'm looking for a more universal solution than hardcoding each name break separately. As to matches() - not available in Xpath 1.0.
